# How to set child user controls data context with PRISM WPF

Tags: wpf, navigation, user-controls, prism

I have a search results grid, when selected any row they should be able to edit the selected item. When clicked on edit, I want to load other user control(this control has its own view model) with selected item details in the same view. 
Using event aggregator to pass info to view model.

How to load the user controls dynamic?

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the desired view?

Comment: from ribbon when user clicks on search, will load the search results grid in a region.On click of edit want to load the user control below the grid.I want to pass selected row details to the child view Model.

Comment: What prevents you from navigating the region below the grid to the desired view with the selected row data as navigation parameters? You might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420238/prism-viewmodellocator-creates-the-view-model-instances-but-how-can-i-target/44420896#44420896